# How To Use Hyperlinks With Spaces In a Hyperlink Column Of A List

Tags: list

I created a new SP 2010 List of Hyperlinks using the SP2010 Hyperlinks List Template.  It works so long as the hyperlinks/URL contains no spaces.  When viewing the list one can click on any link and be taken to the specified URL.  When the hyperlink contains a space such as is the case with some network directories like `\\FileServer\Manuals\Docs & Guides\` The SP list considers the hyperlink to be only the part up until the first space.  When viewing the list and clicking on an entry with a space in the URL you are taken to the incorrect location.  How di I get the URL column of the SP210 List to treaty to full hyperlink as the hyperlink and not just the portion up until the first space?

How can I add the below URL/Hyperlink to the list so that when someone is viewing the list and they click on the hyperlink they will be taken to the location listed below?

```
\\FileServer\Manuals\Docs & Guides\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace the space with %20

so your link should look like this:

```
\FileServer\Manuals\Docs%20&%20Guides\
```

In c#:

```
"someString".Replace(" ", "%20");
```

I do the same with normal URL and it works like a charm.

cheers Jürgen

Comment: Thanks Jurgen.  This is the asnwer i needed.  How to add the URL not programatically but copy & paste or just manually typing it in.  This is a list of URLs & Shortcuts for all our users to make use of and add to.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your url I would recommend removing the space or %20 you can use this that iv just made. pass the url string that you need to remove and it will return the url string without any spaces :)

```
    public static string RemoveURLSpaces(string url)
    {
        url = url.Replace(" ", "");

        return url;
    }
```